# How to make a Lenovo Ideapad Z510 as dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, lenovo

I am planning to go for a Lenovo Ideapad Z510 which comes along with Windows 8.1. Now I need to install Ubuntu (Linux) on it. So how do I go about making the system dual boot? Which version of Ubuntu should I use?

I am doing this for the first time, so a detailed explanation will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer comes with Windows 8.1 pre-installed, it will make use of the complete disk space.

The first thing you need to do, is create space for your Ubuntu installation. You can either use your Windows Disk Management (can be found in your computer management console) or you can use gparted. There are dedicated boot cd's you can download with gparted or you can launch it from a Linux LiveCD. Both ways give you an easy graphical interface in which you can resize (shrink) your Windows partition.

You download your preferred Linux Distro (Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 is a really nice option for beginners!). 64-bit versions are offered by defaut, but there are STILL some applications (e.g. skype) that really prefer 32-bit versions. So for absolute beginners, I still advise you to get the 32-bit version. You will read that a 32-bit can't use more than 4GB of RAM, but Ubuntu comes with PAE (Physical Address Extention) pre-installed, so it should see a lot more. Don't worry about this, your RAM will not go to waste. When you've got the ISO, is't always good to check the MD5sum of the file, to check for any errors before you start your installation. I can't remember when I had the last bad iso downloaded, but it's always a good habit to do so... Anyways, when you have the iso file, you can opt to write a DVD, or go over to http://pendrivelinux.net to download the Universal USB Installer and create your bootable USB key.

When all that is done, you're ready for your first dual-boot installation. Restart your computer, choose to boot from USB or CD, whichever you created, and follow easy install instructions. BE WARNED! Quite a few people here have complained that they lost their Windows after installing Ubuntu (or other Linux distros) because they didn't read or understand all the actions you go through before installing. Before you press the button Install Now, make sure you've chosen to install Ubuntu in the FREE SPACE, next to your Windows. So don't choose to use your whole disk ;) Should you not see this option, abort the installation and come back for help.

After the installation, you should be left with a working Windows and Ubuntu. After booting, you will see the bootloader GRUB pop up, offering you the choice between Ubuntu and Windows. If you don't like the default OS, you can manually change that later.

After all this, you should also consider running Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Especially when you have no experience with Ubuntu, it may be a bit easier to switch between an OS that you know and feel comfortable with and the OS you want to learn about. Windows 8.1 comes with Hyper-V, or you can opt to install VirtualBox or VMware Player for free. Personally, I prefer VirtualBox, but that's just me... Hyper-V works well too and doesn't require 3rd-party software, but it has few limitations that, at this point, you don't have to worry about. Most new computers these days are more than powerful enough for you to run at least 1 virtual machine. It saves you from doing risky things like resizing your partition and you'll be able to run both OS's at the same time. This also gives you the option to test or play around with network sharing, communication between your Windows and Linux, etc, which is pretty difficult to do in a dual-boot situation.

Comment: With partition actions, always make sure you stay clear from your recovery partition (that has your Windows image). Or if you want to get rid of it, make sure you created the necessary backups (see manual) to avoid difficult situations in the future!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I will try using your second suggestion first, and I will actually make it dual boot only if it is absolutely necessary.