# Lenovo Z510 Ubuntu Disk Partition

Tags: partitioning, lenovo, disk

I have Lenovo z510 laptop and i want to install Ubuntu but i need your suggestions.
I have 8 GB ssd and 1Tb hard disk.
How can i divide to the disk?

Actually, i want to learn about size of partition for example:

Sda1 300 GB,
Sda2 500 GB. and swap area? Also there are ext4,ext3 and ext2 as i understand difference is that ext4 is the newest so should i choose as ext4?

How should be order of partitions. By the way,

My situation is a little bit different. My computer came without operating system for a while i used Windows 8 than i decided to use free and open source operating system. Also i want to develop Java and PHP applications. Than i installed Ubuntu but My Home gave error because of inadequate disk space. So I wanted to ask ideal disk space of partition size. I lost Windows if i want to install windows 8.1 beside of Ubuntu what should i do. And if i want to backup where should i reserve.

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Disregard the 8 GB drive. I recommend having a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes#Basic_Partitioning_Scheme_for_a_2TB_Desktop_HDD.

Answer (score 0):

1. The 8gb ssd is only used to speed up the boot process. It cannot be used separately. *Don't touch it*.
2. Your computer comes preinstalled with Windows 8.1 which takes all the disk space.  You can use use a GParted Live CD or the Windows disk management console to make some *free space* to install Ububntu.

*Please take both points above in mind* or you might loose your Windows 8.1!

3. *Ideally* there are 3 partitions needed to install Linux: BOOT, SWAP, ROOT. The SDA1 and SDA2 you see are partitions currently present on your laptop. First you have to define the boot volume in GB. Set it identical to your RAM size. Set the swap space to double of that your RAM. Both the SWAP space and BOOT space will be used by Ubuntu itself, not by you.  For a 100GB hard drive space on your computer, Boot space should be 8GB, swap space 16GB, Root space 76GB.
4. While you install on SDA1 or SDA2 just ensure that you have chosen the *free disk space* saved for Ubuntu in step 1! You will not be able to use this space in Windows. If you use the windows disk console, make a separate partition say of 100 gb. Don't use that space and don't even format it. That way, while installing Ubuntu you can easily identify the space as it will be mentioned as free space/unpartitioned.
   Select that partition. Only use that partition and verify twice!

Now define your BOOT, SWAP, ROOT partitions for Ubuntu as mentioned above.
Don't worry your windows will be safe as there will be dual boot.

For more information on dual boot see the link :
[How to make a Lenovo Ideapad Z510 as dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488805/how-to-make-a-lenovo-ideapad-z510-as-dual-boot)

Comment: For most beginning users, SWAP, ROOT and HOME are the ideal number of partitions...  :P  ;-)
Also, review the edits I made to help you get even better then you already are!  :-)